# dependent picklists reset when you forget to fill in a required field and try to move to the next screen in a Salesforce Screen Flow

Tags: screen-flow, dependent-picklist, required-field

I have a situation where requiered dependent picklists reset when I forget to fill in a required field and try to move to the next screen in a Salesforce Screen Flow. Even if "Use values from when the user last visited this screen" is ticked in the advanced option.

How can I handle that issu

Answer (score 0):

I found that with a default like : {contact.Email}  can do the job.

And thank's everyone for the answer

Ps: didn't find that aniway